# How to remove first character from each element of an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings. I want to remove first character from each element of that array.

I looped through the array and tried to remove the first character by using substr method.

```js
 var x = ["X2019","X2020","X2021","X2022"];
    
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  result = x[i].substr(1);
}
console.log(result);
```

I need an array like

`result = ["2019","2021","2022"];`

Comment: In your example, `result` is not an array. Second, `substr` returns a new string. Third try functional looping methods like `Array.map`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) methods to get the desired output:

```js
var x = ["X2019","X2020","X2021","X2022"];

var y = x.map(s => s.slice(1));

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing value returned from `substr()` call in a loop. Assigning to a variable means only the last value will be available.

Declare a `result` `array` and `push` to it.

```js
var x = ["X2019", "X2020", "X2021", "X2022"];
var result = []
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    result.push(x[i].substr(1));
}
console.log(result);
```

Even the shorter syntax by using `map()` function:

```js
var x = ["X2019", "X2020", "X2021", "X2022"];
var result = x.map(value => value.substr(1));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please note that answering a question this obvious is bad practice. Since you know the solution, you are more likely to form better query for such issues. You should search and vote to close such question as there are other ways and discussions that will help everyone